# Is having a static homepage harmful for my SEO?

Tags: seo, static-content, homepage

My homepage is a static page, *not* a page showing latest posts.

Is this harmful for my SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it's actually **better** for SEO. The reason for this, is because you're telling search engines exactly what you're about, and that isn't changing (or drastically changing). You can have H1 and H2 tags that are extremely relevant to your niche, control your outbound links 100%, and link to the other most important content on your site (further alerting search engines of what you're all about).

Comment: To provide a counterargument, fresh up to date content could also help boosting your rank. The opposite of your answer :)

Comment: I generally prefer a hybrid myself. Enough static content to keep the core idea solid, but have a few sections that are dynamic. In general though, the rest of the site is constantly updating, which search engines will see, so the home page being static / mostly static won't harm you.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a non static home pages the only benefit you get is updated content, but unless your content is very tightly themed then you risk confussing Google and not ranking as highlighy. Let me give you an example say you have a website that is about London, but you home page changes and sometimes it is about Birmingham how is Google going to know to rank it for London. Your on page will say Birmingham sometimes and your links will always be changing (inbound) that is. KIIS Keep it Simple Stupid and Google and other search engines will understand.